# Find the value of a so that the 2 x 2 matrix A is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find the value of a so that the $2 \times 2$ matrix

$A = \begin{pmatrix} a-3 & 1\\ 2a+14 & a \\  \end{pmatrix}$

is invertible.

do I just use the $\frac{1}{ad-bc}$ rule and solve for $a$, then conclude it is invertible for any value not $0$?

Comment: Yes, using the determinant is a good idea, particularly for a $2\times 2$ where computation is simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is good.  The determinant is $(a-3)a-1(2a+14)$  Unless this is zero the matrix is invertible.  As it is quadratic, there should be two values of $a$ that are excluded.